# AWS Serverless deployment error NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless-framework

I have a fairly basic NodeJS API that I have built offline using the serverless framework for AWS in NodeJS. I have gotten it working fine in the offline configuration however when I try to deploy I initially got the following log error:

```
Unable to import module 'services/tv/get/handler': Error
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I found a few threads on GitHub talking about a similar issue [in this thread](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/issues/383), however after going over it I couldn't make any of the fixes work in my situation. I have checked the deployed zip file and it seems to have the dependancies required.

**Serverless.yml**

```
service: show-stoppers-lambda

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 10
  stage: production
  region: ap-southeast-1

functions:

  getNowAiringTv:
    handler: services/tv/get/handler.getNowAiringTv
    events:
      - http:
          path: tv/now
          method: get
          cors: true

  getTvShowDetails:
    handler: services/tv/get/handler.getShowDetails
    events:
      - http:
          path: tv/{showId}
          method: get
          cors: true

  getTvShowSearch:
    handler: services/tv/get/handler.getShowSearch
    events:
      - http:
          path: tv/search/{query}
          method: get
          cors: true

  getDiscoverTvFilter:
    handler: services/tv/get/handler.getDiscoverTv
    events:
      - http:
          path: tv/filter
          method: get
          cors: true

  getSimilarTvShows:
    handler: services/tv/get/handler.getSimilarShows
    events:
      - http:
          path: tv/similar/{showId}
          method: get
          cors: true

  getTvSeasonDetail:
    handler: services/tv/get/handler.getTvSeasons
    events:
      - http:
          path: tv/{showId}/{season}
          method: get
          cors: true

  getTvSeasonEpisodeDetail:
    handler: services/tv/get/handler.getTvEpisodes
    events:
      - http:
          path: tv/{showId}/{season}/{episode}
          method: get
          cors: true


plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "show-stoppers-lambda",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "alex",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-offline": "^3.25.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.5",
    "request": "^2.87.0"
  }
}
```

The full code is on my [github here](https://github.com/anontyro/show-stoppers/tree/master/show-stoppers-lambda) and I have included a [package.zip here](https://github.com/anontyro/show-stoppers/blob/master/show-stoppers-lambda.zip) which contains the contents (.env emptied prior). I am hoping someone is able to show me where I am going wrong with this I have seen some suggestions prior to use serverless-webpack but for something small like this I am not sure it is required, also I am not sure how to set it up either to work here.

**Update**

I have found the reason I have been getting a lot of 500 errors is due to Request, I am still unclear as to why as the dependency seems to be included in the zip but maybe it is missing one it requires on top of that. I will look over it more in a bit but currently I have worked around this by using a simple implementation of HTTPS module and now the requests are all firing correctly

Comment: Can you edit the question to make it clearer? I thought you were having problem loading your handler function - `Unable to import module 'services/tv/get/handler': Error`. Might be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the correct file? Your `handler.js` code seems to have only one function `hello` which needs to be referenced as `handler.hello`. If this was just a dummy file for asking the question here, try referencing the function in yaml as `handler.<function-name>`

Comment: yeah there is a dummy file in the main I forgot to remove but the yml is pointing to the services/tv/get/handler so that should work surely?

Comment: I also tried to restructure and just change the base handler to the one in service/tv/get and it still has the same issue yet it continues to work locally

Comment: What I meant was, update your yaml spec to refer to the handler as `handler: handler.getNowAiringTv`. Surely when I added the `services/tv/get/` to a working serverless yaml spec, although `sls deploy` showed no error, lambda console for the particular function was in error `The file services/tv/get/handler.js could not be found. Make sure your handler upholds the format: file-name.method.` So just remove that from the yaml spec and it will work.

Comment: this wasn't the issue in this case it was indeed the dependency request which was causing errors, when I switch over to using the https module it all worked fine. I am still not sure what the issue is with Request here but is it really annoying., Thanks for the help anyway @ASR